# How to count every half hour?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that its counting every hour, using a pivot table.
How would it be possible to get the count for every 30 minutes?

for example 8:00-8:29,8:30-8:59,9:00-9:29 etc. until 5:00

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),start_date,1) AS 'Day',

       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as eight ,

       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nine,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ten,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS eleven,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS twelve,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS one_clock,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS two_clock,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS three_clock,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS four_clock

FROM  test
where user_id is not null 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(8),start_date,1)
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(8),start_date,1)
```

I use sql server 2012 (version Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128.0)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `iif` as below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),start_date,1) AS 'Day', SUM(iif(DATEPART(hour,start_date) = 8 and
 DATEPART(minute,start_date) >= 0 and
 DATEPART(minute,start_date) =< 29,1,0)) as eight_tirty 
    FROM test where user_id is not null GROUP BY
 CONVERT(varchar(8),start_date,1) ORDER BY
 CONVERT(varchar(8),start_date,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get counts by day and half hour, something like this should work.

```
SELECT day, half_hour, count(1) AS half_hour_count
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CAST(start_date AS date) AS day, 
        DATEPART(hh, start_date) 
            + 0.5*(DATEPART(n,start_date)/30) AS half_hour
    FROM test
    WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
) qry
GROUP BY day, half_hour
ORDER BY day, half_hour;
```

Formatting the result could be done later.

Answer (score 1):

You need a few things, and then this query just falls together.

First, assuming you need multiple dates, you're going to want what's known as a [`Calendar Table`](http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) (hands down, probably the most useful analysis table).

Next, you're going to want either an existing `Numbers` table if you have one, or just generate the first on the fly:

```
WITH Halfs AS (SELECT CAST(0 AS INT) m
               UNION ALL
               SELECT m + 1
               FROM Halfs
               WHERE m < 24 * 2)
SELECT m
FROM Halfs
```

(recursive CTE - generates a table with a list of numbers starting at 0).

These two tables will provide the basis for a range query based on the timestamps in your main table.  This will make it very easy for the optimizer to bucket rows for whatever aggregation you're doing.  That's done by `CROSS JOIN`ing the two tables together in a subquery, as well as adding a couple of other derived columns:

```
WITH Halfs AS (SELECT CAST(0 AS INT) m
               UNION ALL
               SELECT m + 1
               FROM Halfs
               WHERE m < 24 * 2)

SELECT calendarDate, m, rangeStart, rangeEnd
FROM (SELECT Calendar.calendarDate, Halfs.m rangeGroup,
             DATEADD(minutes, m * 30, CAST(Calendar.calendarDate AS DATETIME2) rangeStart,
             DATEADD(minutes, (m + 1) * 30, CAST(Calendar.calendarDate AS DATETIME2) rangeEnd                 
      FROM Calendar
      CROSS JOIN Halfs
      WHERE Calendar.calendarDate >= CAST('20160823' AS DATE)
            AND Calendar.calendarDate < CAST('20160830' AS DATE)
            -- OR whatever your date range actually is.
     ) Range
ORDER BY rangeStart
```

(note that, if the range of dates is sufficiently large, it may be beneficial to save this off as a temporary table with indicies.  For small tables and datasets, the performance gain isn't likely to be noticeable)

Now that we have our ranges, it's trivial to get our groups, and pivot the table.
Oh, and SQL Server has a specific operator for [`PIVOT`ing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).

```
WITH Halfs AS (SELECT CAST(0 AS INT) m
               UNION ALL
               SELECT m + 1
               FROM Halfs
               WHERE m < 3 * 2)
               -- Intentionally limiting range for example only

SELECT calendarDate AS day, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]
                            -- If you're displaying "nice" names,
                            -- do it at this point, or in the reporting application
FROM (SELECT Range.calendarDate, Range.rangeGroup
      FROM (SELECT Calendar.calendarDate, Halfs.m rangeGroup,
                   DATEADD(minutes, m * 30, CAST(Calendar.calendarDate AS DATETIME2) rangeStart,
                   DATEADD(minutes, (m + 1) * 30, CAST(Calendar.calendarDate AS DATETIME2) rangeEnd                 
                   FROM Calendar
                   CROSS JOIN Halfs
                   WHERE Calendar.calendarDate >= CAST('20160823' AS DATE)
                         AND Calendar.calendarDate < CAST('20160830' AS DATE)
                         -- OR whatever your date range actually is.
                   ) Range
      LEFT JOIN Test
             ON Test.user_id IS NOT NULL
                AND Test.start_date >= Range.rangeStart
                AND Test.start_date < Range.rangeEnd
     ) AS DataTable
PIVOT (COUNT(*)
       FOR Range.rangeGroup IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])) AS PT
                                -- Only covers the first 6 groups, 
                                -- or the first three hours.  
ORDER BY day
```

The pivot should take care of the getting individual columns, and `COUNT` will automatically resolve null rows.  Should be all you need.